# How do I prevent LibreOffice update from reassigning the default program for .doc?

Tags: libreoffice, ninite

When using Ninite to silently update Windows XP computers in a lab environment, LibreOffice reassigns the default program for the .doc file type from MS Office 2010 to LibreOffice. How can this be prevented?